# How to count the number of integers in every row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the one below:

```
df = structure(list(`1` = c(-1, NA, NA, NA, -1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `3` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    `4` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `5` = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, NA, NA, NA, NA), `6` = c(NA, 
    NA, -1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `7` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    -1, NA), `8` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `9` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, NA, NA, NA, NA), `10` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")

    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  -1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3  NA NA NA NA NA -1 NA NA NA NA
4  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0 NA
5  -1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
6  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA -1
7  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
8  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
9  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
10 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
11 NA NA NA NA -1 NA NA NA -1 NA
12 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
13 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
14 NA NA NA NA NA NA -1 NA NA NA
15 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

What I want to do is to get how many times integers appear in each row. I tried this (and variants):

```
rowSums(df != "NA")
```

However, it doesn't work. I would like a code to tell me simply how many times appear in each row.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `!is.na` with `rowSums` to count the times you have no `NA` per row like:

```
rowSums(!is.na(df))
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
# 1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `Reduce`

```
ncol(df) - Reduce(`+`, lapply(df, is.na))
#[1] 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 0
```